# WebDriverBackedSelenium Wait Time Out Was unhandled.

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

webdriverbackedselenium throwing unhandled exception when use WaitForPageToLoad(timeout);
Even i have try catch

```
     try
        {
            selenium.WaitForPageToLoad(timeout);                
        }
        catch
        {               

        }
```

Catching its exception, but when it comes out of catch, showing this image[image]

Tried many solutions but didn't succeeded , please advise what should i Do.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may configure the  [Exception Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/197c1fsc(v=vs.110).aspx) dialog in the way to receive or not receive the exception even if you have the catch block. The solution in the Exceptions configuration you have. Please see it under Debug->Exceptions menu. If the exception checkbox is checked you will receive the Exception Assistant dialog (under debug!) even you have the catch block in your code.
Please see more details and pictures [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Visual-Studio-Exceptions-Dialogs.aspx)